# How to transpose pandas dataframe from multiple rows with same name to single column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have tried to convert multiple rows with same name into single column but did not get exactly. I have done code for single and its mentioned in the following.

```
import pandas as pd 
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gambler2020/Data_Analysis/master/population/population.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(url)
df
```

[Image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFlc.png)
The above code used to read and see the data frame from github.But the problem is that there are various countries and each country has hundreds of rows and i want to convert those each country having various rows into single column. The following code is for converting single countries with various rows into one column.

```
dff=df["Year"].head(259)
dff
a1=df[df["Entity"]=="Paraguay"]
a1=a1.rename(columns={"Population (historical estimates)": "Paraguay"})
a1=a1["Paraguay"]
a1=a1.reset_index(drop=True)
a1
dff=pd.concat([dff, a1], axis=1)
dff
```

[image of output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS9su.png)
This image is the sample of desired dataframe but it will take time to do for each countries because there are hundreds of countries. How do i write code so that i could convert raw dataframe [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRFlc.png) into desired output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS9su.png) for all the countries.

Answer (score 1):

[`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
[image: Reshaping and pivot table]

```
result = df.pivot(index='Year', columns='Entity', values='Population (historical estimates)').reset_index()
result.columns.name = None
result

###
      Year  Afghanistan        Africa    Albania     Algeria  American Samoa  …
0   -10000      14737.0  2.276110e+05     1199.0     12090.0             NaN  …
1    -9000      20405.0  3.230350e+05     1999.0     20150.0             NaN  … 
2    -8000      28253.0  4.629670e+05     3332.0     33583.0             NaN  … 
3    -7000      39120.0  6.700190e+05     5554.0     55973.0             NaN  … 
4    -6000      54166.0  9.791040e+05     9256.0     93289.0             NaN  … 
..     ...          ...           ...        ...         ...             ...   
254   2017   36296111.0  1.244222e+09  2884169.0  41389174.0         55617.0  …   
255   2018   37171922.0  1.275921e+09  2882735.0  42228415.0         55461.0  … 
256   2019   38041757.0  1.308064e+09  2880913.0  43053054.0         55312.0  …

[259 rows x 245 columns]
```